# Am I able to hide children display object if the exceed the parent display object height?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, jwplayer, displayobject

Hey I building a plugin for a player, and I create a few sprites.

The first spirte is a background, it's a black color alpha at .6. Then I add n children to it, depending on what video users are viewing.

The background's width and height is .75 of the actually width and height of the player and the children I am adding are 34 pixels each, they are added in via an array.

I have an issue when the player is small, the children combine width is greater than the parents width.

So I wanted to know if there is a way to hide the children or have stay with in the parent height so it won't overflow. And when you mouse over it scrolls up and down.

Thanks

This demo doesn't overflow but just picture 4 more links, clicking the shopping logo when it comes up

http://elvis.rowan.edu/~majeko02/http-f/JWPLayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a mask on the parent defined exactly at the dimensions you want the  player to be ?